# SQL : search from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and I have two tables

`player`:

```
    player  guildId
--------------------
    a       1
    b       2
    c       2
    d       2
    e       1
    f       1
    g       1
```

`game`:

```
    player  gameId
--------------------
    a       4
    b       1
    c       2
    d       1
    e       3
    f       2
    g       2
```

I want to create a view called view_test,

The view's result :

```
select * from view_test where guildId = 2 and gameId = 2
```

it shows

```
  player joined
----------------
    b    false
    c    true
    d    false


select * from view_test where guildId = 2 and gameId = 1

   player joined
-----------------
    b     true
    c     false
    d     true

select * from view_test where guildId = 2 and gameId = 3

  player joined
----------------
    b    false
    c    false
    d    false

select * from view_test where guildId = 1 and gameId = 4

  player joined
----------------
    a    true
    e    false
    f    false
    g    false
```

How can I do this SQL ?

Thanks

Comment: Please show what did you tried and where get stacked?

Comment: Could you indicate the structure of the tables? From the expected results you show you seem to be wanting a LEFT JOIN on the a, b, c, etc... but you do not tell us what those columns are in the two tables.

Comment: I trying the JOIN:

Select * from player
left join game on game.PlayerId=player.PlayerId
where guildId=2

it's show players in guild 2 , three players.
when I add the where condition " and gameid=1" , it can't shows all guild players

Comment: @A-U: You showed guildId instead of gameId in your games table. I've corrected this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cross join players with all game IDs to get all possible combinations first. Then you look the combination up in the games table. So base the view on:

```
select player.player, player.guildid, gameids.gameid,
  case when 
  (
    select count(*) 
    from game 
    where game.player = player.player 
    and game.gameid = gameids.gameid
  ) > 0 then 'true' else 'false' end as joined
from player
cross join (select distinct gameid from game) gameids;
```

The statement

```
select * from view_test where guildId=2 and gameId=2
```

would result in

```
  player  guildId  gameid  joined
---------------------------------
    b     2        2       false
    c     2        2       true
    d     2        2       false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Like This

```
select id,case when count(*)=2 then 'true' else
'false' end from (
select id from player where guildId=2
union all 
select id from game where gameId=2
) as tt group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query my friend:

```
with t as
(select t1.id,t1.guildId,t2.gameId  from player t1,game t2 where t1.id = t2.id)
select id,case when gameId = var.VarGameId then 'True'else 'False' end as Joined from t, 
(select 1 as VarGameId, 2 as VarGuildId)var where t.guildId = var.VarGuildId;
```

you can use something like `var` in my query to change the `variables.`

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18d47/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check for one guild (or a limited number) and one game (or a limited number), then you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT p.player
  , (EXISTS (SELECT player FROM game WHERE player=p.player AND gameId=1)) AS joined
FROM player p
WHERE p.guildId=2
```

I would not create a view though... as that would require a complete cartesian join of all players with all distinct games. I wouldn't be so sure that once you select from that view the engine will be able to optimize the access through the view to the underlying tables and indices and give you results in reasonable time.

The view could be something like this though:

```
SELECT p.player, p.guildId, g.gameId
  , (EXISTS (SELECT player FROM game WHERE player=p.player AND gameId=g.gameId)) AS joined
FROM player p JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT gameId FROM game) g
```

I must add... I don't use SQLServer... I'm not sure it supports the EXISTS subselect expression.